# Can Milky Way be seen in South hemisphere only?

Tags: observational-astronomy, milky-way

I heard something(long time ago) that Milky Way can be seen in South hemisphere only, is it true? If so, what is the reason?

Comment: You might be thinking of the Magellanic Clouds, island galaxies closer to the Milky Way than the Andromeda Galaxy.

Answer (score 5):

That is not true. The band of the Milky Way can be seen from any latitude on the planet. It just requires the right time of year and a dark sky.

Answer (score 0):

The band of milky way is inclined by more than $60\deg$ to the celestial equator. Hence, it can be **easily seen from the southern hemisphere.**

In fact, **the milky way center lies in Sagittarius (a southern hemisphere constellation)**, which means,

> **The Milky Way would look better in the Southern Hemisphere.**